Generic clock consumer in the common clock framework
In my setup, there is a clock generator that use the common clock framework in the Linux kernel. The clock generator has an output clock that I would like to feed to an external connector. If I have understood the common clock framework correctly, the generic setup is the following:
source_clock --> clock modifier (mux, gate, pll, ...) --> clock consumer

I'm not quite sure I understand the clock consumer part. By default, the clocks are disabled and are only enabled when a consumer (which I assume to always be a driver) enables them. Does this always have to be a specific driver? What if, like in my case, the clock should only be forwarded to some external connector? Similarly, what if the clock is fed to some FPGA pin where a dedicated driver doesn't really make sense? Am I missing some generic clock consumer that "just requests some output frequency and enables the clock", similar to the fixed-clock producer?
